# Commit project not showing Commit Changes to Git Repository pop up window in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, github

I want to uploate my manven project to github an watching

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r5C6yXNaSGo

4.46 time in the video, there is "Commit Changes to Git Repository" pop up window.
But When I do it, it doesn't pop up such window at all.
Instead what I have is as follows. I don't see file structure to commit.
I'm using sts 3.7.3. and installed egit plugins.

What did I do wrong? I followed the instruction in the video.
Any help? I just want to submit my project to git. that's all.

[image]

Comment: You know that could just be a UI change that was made between the 2013 video and now.

Answer (score 6):

Please un-check "Use staging view...." under Preferences>Git>Committing in your eclipse.

Comment: I think this exactly answers the question. It seems the default for commits  has changed to show the staging window instead of showing the (modal) commit dialog. Just had this with a new Eclipse install.